# HTML Images from folder do not appear anymore (PHP)

Tags: php, html

Title, it just shows the alt name. I checked the source code and it was the same as what I wrote, everything seems to be fine. The file is in the exact location.

```
echo '<img src="https://mywebsite.ca/images/test.jpg" alt="test" title="Test" />';
```

There is a folder in the root called "images" and the file is called test, jpg file. Everything is in working order.

Edit: It does exist in both the server and in the images folder in the disk, but despite this it 404s

Comment: Check the Network panel in the Developer Tools of the browser and see what responses are returned for the image file requests.

Comment: Comes up as red, type is "text" if that helps, 404 not found. I dont use dev tools sorry.

Comment: load your image url in the browser - `https://mywebsite.ca/images/test.jpg` and check if it loads or not. if not then your htaccess caused the issue.

Comment: @Gabe did you check the folder that your image exists with that name? 404 means - it's not exists.

Comment: Yep, in the real images folder (not inside server) it does exist. I have no idea

Comment: you should keep the folder root of your file's directory on that website. also not understand what do you mean by real images folder

Comment: What I mean by "real" folder is the one that exists in the actual computer's disk, not in the server

Comment: buddy! you need to keep the folder in your server. I think you are running your website on a live server not in localhost.

Comment: Yes, it is in my server. There are two of the exact same folders, one on the disk and one on the server, so it is on my server. Also, the website needs to be running on a live server, however I will try to see if it works on localhost.

Comment: so you need to check your server's image folder that your image exists or not. I think it's not exists there, as you were getting 404 error while you were loading the image url in the browser directly.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try it with

```html
echo '<img src="/images/test.jpg" alt="test" title="Test" />';
```

yet?

Comment: Why should it work? And this is not an answer but a follow up question